# Como obtener los puntos de las coordenadas cercanas a mi en android?

Tags: android, google-maps, apigoogle

Tengo una aplicación `android` que tiene unos puntos georeferenciados y muestra ciertos puntos que el usuario pide con un `spinner`, es una consulta a la base local. La pregunta es ¿Cómo mostrar los puntos que están en un radio de 1 km a partir de mi ubicación?

```
criaderosMap = criaderoDao.queryBuilder()
                .where(CtlPlCriaderoDao.Properties.Latitud.isNotNull()).list();
```

Ese código me trae todos los puntos de la Base de Datos, allí podria filtrar por un campo que tenga relación pero necesito consultar los cercanos en 1 km.

Creería que se puede hacer con un between.

Comment: que BBDD utilizas? en mysql 5.7 hay una funcion para calcular distancias entre puntos. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html. Revisa este ejemplo, que puede venirte bien: https://tighten.co/blog/a-mysql-distance-function-you-should-know-about

Comment: la base del dispositivo es sqlite

Comment: entonces quizas puedas utilizar este enlace. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/find-points-within-a-distance-using-mysql.  hay una sql en la que utilizando radianes en Long y lat del punto, te da distancia. Puedes probar eso

Comment: No vas a poder resolverlo desde la base de datos porque las coordenadas lat y lon no corresponden linealmente a una distancia, dependiendo la latitud un grado en longitud puede reprensentar mas o menos distancia. Lo que podrias hacer es pre filtrar con un Between en la base de datos, para no tener que trabajar con toda la tabla, y luego pasarle un filtro usando un ciclo y calculando la distancia para cada resultado.

Comment: ESPERO QUE TE AYUDE Además se deberá declarar en el fichero AndroidManifest.xml el permiso que permitirá a la API determinar la ubicación más precisa posible a través de los proveedores de ubicaciones disponibles, entre los que se incluyen el sistema de posicionamiento global (GPS) y los datos de Wi-Fi y los datos móviles: https://academiaandroid.com/geolocalizacion-obtencion-coordenadas-desde-app-android/

Comment: El enlace de @Jakala de stackoverflow tiene una respuesta que debería valerte: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/66673/154

Comment: He oído hablar de SpatiaLite para SQLite pero la verdad nunca la he usado. Supongo que si en un futuro necesitaras alguna operación espacial más compleja que calcular una distancia deberíais echarle un ojo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Una forma para filtrarlos puede ser desde la [consulta SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339764/get-the-georeferenced-points-near-me-with-android/52398340#52398340) y obtener los que se encuentren a una distancia menor a 1000 metros (`distance < 1000`) :

```
select
    latitud ,
    longitude,
    ( 3959 * acos(  cos( radians(37) )
                  * cos( radians( latitud ) )
                  * cos( radians( longitude) - radians(YourLongitude) )
                  + sin( radians(YourLatitude) ) * sin( radians( latitud ) )
                 )
    ) AS distance
FROM
    ctlCriadero
HAVING
    distance < 1000 
ORDER BY
    distance
LIMIT
    0 , 50
```

---

También mediante Android SDK puedes también realizar la comparación de los valores de geolocalización mediante el método [**distanceTo()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location))

```
    //Device Location
    Location locationDevice = new Location("Android Device Location.");
    locationDevice.setLatitude(deviceLatitude);
    locationDevice.setLongitude(deviceLongitude);
    //Location to compare
    Location locationValue = new Location("location value.");
    locationValue.setLatitude(rLatitude); //Latitud
    locationValue.setLongitude(rLongitude); //Longitud

    //Obtiene distancia en metros.
    float distanceInMeters =  locationDevice.distanceTo(locationValue);
```

---

Este sería un ejemplo,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde el método `comparePrintInfo()` realiza la comparación para imprimir que localizaciones se encuentran en el rango de un kilómetro.

Debes modificar el método `getListOfPostitions()` para que obtenga la lista de posiciones a comparar, probablemente desde un servicio.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int ONE_KM = 1000; //1 km

    private static final long MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute.
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES = (long) 1.5; // 1.5 meters
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private ArrayList<Address> listOfGeoPositions;
    private TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 225);
        }else{

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

            Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            comparePrintInfo(location);

        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());

        comparePrintInfo(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStatusChanged("  + s +")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProviderEnabled("  + s +")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled("  + s +")");
    }

    //This method uses distanceTo() that returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and the given location.
    private float getDistance(double deviceLatitude, double deviceLongitude, double rLatitude, double rLongitude){

        //Device Location
        Location locationDevice = new Location("Android Device Location.");
        locationDevice.setLatitude(deviceLatitude);
        locationDevice.setLongitude(deviceLongitude);
        //Location to compare
        Location locationValue = new Location("location value.");
        locationValue.setLatitude(rLatitude); //Latitud
        locationValue.setLongitude(rLongitude); //Longitud

        //distanceTo()
        //https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)
        //Returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and the given location.
        return locationDevice.distanceTo(locationValue);
    }

    /*TODO: Jorgesys, * Very important to change this method to get your geolocation points to be compared with the position of your device*/
    private ArrayList<Address> getListOfPostitions(){

        listOfGeoPositions = new ArrayList<Address>();
        Address geoPosition;
        geoPosition = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
        geoPosition.setFeatureName("Palas Ice Skating Rink.");
        geoPosition.setLatitude(47.156116);
        geoPosition.setLongitude(27.5864219);
        listOfGeoPositions.add(geoPosition);
        geoPosition = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
        geoPosition.setFeatureName("Gradina publica IASI.");
        geoPosition.setLatitude(25.6723275);
        geoPosition.setLongitude(-100.3101152);
        listOfGeoPositions.add(geoPosition);
        geoPosition = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
        geoPosition.setFeatureName("Platz Bierhaus.");
        geoPosition.setLatitude(25.667943);
        geoPosition.setLongitude(-100.3103716);
        listOfGeoPositions.add(geoPosition);
        geoPosition = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
        geoPosition.setFeatureName("Palatul Cultura.");
        geoPosition.setLatitude(47.1557913);
        geoPosition.setLongitude(27.5861617);
        listOfGeoPositions.add(geoPosition);
        geoPosition = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
        geoPosition.setFeatureName("Equestrian statue of Stefan cel Mare.");
        geoPosition.setLatitude(47.1573927);
        geoPosition.setLongitude(27.5863307);
        listOfGeoPositions.add(geoPosition);

        return listOfGeoPositions;
    }


    private void comparePrintInfo(Location deviceLocation){

        //Get positions to compare with Device position.
        //The method getListOfPostitions() must have the query to get the locations to compare with the device location.
        listOfGeoPositions = getListOfPostitions();
        //Print info.
        String myData= "";
        myData += "<font color=#6ef442>Android</font> Device position:<br><b>Downtown IASI.</b><br>Latitude: " + deviceLocation.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + deviceLocation.getLongitude() + "<br><br>";
        float distance;
        for(int i = 0 ;i<listOfGeoPositions.size();i++) {
            distance = getDistance(deviceLocation.getLatitude(), deviceLocation.getLongitude(), listOfGeoPositions.get(i).getLatitude(), listOfGeoPositions.get(i).getLongitude());
            Log.i(TAG, "Distance calculated: " + distance);
            if(distance < ONE_KM) {
                myData += "<b>" + listOfGeoPositions.get(i).getFeatureName() + "</b><br>latitude: " + listOfGeoPositions.get(i).getLatitude() + ", longitude: " + listOfGeoPositions.get(i).getLongitude() +"<br><font color=#0000FF>Distance in range : " + distance + " mts.</font><br>";
            }else{
                myData += "<b>" +listOfGeoPositions.get(i).getFeatureName() + "</b><br>latitude: " + listOfGeoPositions.get(i).getLatitude() + ", longitude: " + listOfGeoPositions.get(i).getLongitude() +"<br><font color=#FF0000>Distance out of range : " + distance + " mts.</font><br>";
            }
        }
        myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myData));

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Compare locations to device position!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Android tiene una clase [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) que te permite, entre otras cosas calcular la distancia entre dos puntos.

El método que te ayudará en tu caso es [distanceTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) que te retorna la distancia en metros entre dos puntos. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de esta clase en acción :

```
Location madrid = new Location(40.416775, -3.703790); //Centro de Madrid
Location laLatina = new Location(40.411804, -3.708070); //Metro La Latina, Madrid
Location barcelona = new Location(41.385063, 2.173404); // Centro de Barcelona
double distMax = 1000; // 1KM en metros

if( madrid.distanceTo( laLatina ) <= distMax ){
    System.out.println("La distancia entre el centro de Madrid y la Latina es de 1KM ou menos");
}

if( madrid.distanceTo( barcelona ) > distMax ){
    System.out.println("La distancia entre el centro de Madrid y Barcelona es de más de 1KM");
}
```

Comment: pero es que no busco calcular la distancia entre dos puntos si no seleccionar todos los puntos que estan comprendidos en un radio de 1 km

Comment: Entonces especifica en tu pregunta que deseas realizar la operación desde la query a la base de datos. De lo contrario puede crear confusión. De todas formas creo que no es posible con SQLLite.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas parecido que he podido encontrar y funciona es lo siguiente:

```
 select nombre,
        latitud ,
        longitud,
        ( 3959 * acos(  cos( radians(37) )
              * cos( radians( latitud ) )
              * cos( radians( longitud) - radians(-89.29239250) )
              + sin( radians(13.67259696) ) * sin( radians( latitud ) )
             )
) AS distance
FROM
ctl_establecimiento
   GROUP BY LATITUD
   HAVING
   distance < 3000

ORDER BY
distance
 LIMIT
  0 , 5
```

LO he sacado de: [Stackoverflow ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339764/get-the-georeferenced-points-near-me-with-android/52398340#52398340)

Comment: Pero además de esto necesitas obtener la ubicación de tu dispositivo y compararlo con los puntos que deseas es así?

Answer (score 1):

El metodo distanceBetween te puede ayudar, te devuelve la distancia en metros entre dos puntos. Solo tienes que iterarla entre la lista y el punto de partida.

```
void distanceBetween(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, float[] results)
```

El metodo calcula la distancia aproximada en metros entre dos ubicaciones, y opcionalmente los enlaces iniciales y finales del camino más corto entre ellos.

Referencia:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location

Answer (score 0):

Primero trae todos los marcadores de tu base de datos, luego calculas la distancia  entre un marcador y otro con el siguiente código:

```
 public static double calcularDistancia(LatLng a, LatLng b) {
    if (a != null && b != null) {
        // pasamos las diferencias de las coordenadas a radianes
        double difLat = toRadianes(b.latitude - a.latitude);
        double difLong = toRadianes(b.longitude - a.longitude);

        double dato1 = Math.sin(difLat / 2) * Math.sin(difLat / 2) + Math.cos(toRadianes(a.latitude)) *
                Math.cos(toRadianes(b.latitude)) * Math.sin(difLong / 2) * Math.sin(difLong / 2);

        double dato2 = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(dato1), Math.sqrt(1 - dato1));

        double dato3 = RADIO_TIERRA * dato2;

        Log.v(TAG, "Resutlado final (metros) " + dato3 * 1000);

        return dato3 * 1000;// lo pasamos a metros
    }

    return 0.0;// si a y b son nulos
}

private static double toRadianes(double coord) {
    return ((coord * Math.PI) / 180);
}
```

Y para culminar lo que haces es preguntar:

```
if(calcularDistancia(miposicion,mipunto)=>1000){
//aqui llamas la funcion markeroption y le pasas como parametro de newLatLng mi punto
```

}

por cierto si no sabes como recorrer tus puntos, utiliza un `for` y con el `if` es que vas a comparar. Asi puedes mostrar todos los puntos en 1km a la redonda.